# C++ Deleting pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, struct

I'm writing a program which uses structs of pointers and non pointed items and I am trying to properly deallocate my data to reduce overhead (it really matters).

This is what I have. I am essentially making my own queue with specific functionality. My struct simply holds a piece of generic data and a pointer reference to the next spot.

```
template<class T>
struct Spot
{
    T data;
    Spot *spotBehind;
};
```

When I **add a new Element**, I do it with the following code (I keep track of both the head and tail of my queue).

```
if(front == NULL)           //Make first head
    {
        Spot<T> *newSpot = new Spot<T>();
        newSpot->data = newElement;
        newSpot->spotBehind = front;
        front = newSpot;
        back = front;
    }
    else        //Find back of line and add
    {
        Spot<T> *newSpot = new Spot<T>();
        newSpot->data = newElement;
        newSpot->spotBehind = NULL;
        back->spotBehind = newSpot;
        back = newSpot;
    }
```

So after this, when it comes to the destructor, of course I need to have a **delete** for every **new** that I have. So my destructor uses the code:

```
Spot<T> *current = front;
Spot<T> *next = NULL;
while(current != NULL)
{
    next = current->spotBehind;

    delete current;
    current = NULL;

    current = next;
}
```

Now my concern is here. When I use my destructor, I don't think it is doing what it should and I am potentially have memory leaks here. Through various **cout** statements, I can verify my information being stored and working as expected. But when I am deleting the data, it doesn't actually appear to be deleted. To try to debug it, I replaced the reconstructor code (above) with the following to get a sense of what it is doing.

```
while(current != NULL)
{
    next = current->spotBehind;

    cout << "Before Delete " << current << " Data: " << current->data << endl;
    delete current;
    cout << "After Delete " << current << " Data: " << current->data << endl;
    current = NULL;
    cout << "After Null " << current << endl;
    current = next;
    if(current != NULL)
        cout << "After Reassigned " << current << " Data: " << current->data << endl;
}
```

and I get the following results:

```
Before Delete 0x100103b20 Data: 5
After Delete 0x100103b20 Data: 5
After Null 0x0
After Reassigned 0x100103b30 Data: 10
Before Delete 0x100103b30 Data: 10
After Delete 0x100103b30 Data: 10
After Null 0x0
```

## SO THE BIG QUESTION

So my big question is, is the information actually being deallocated the way it is supposed to be. I am thinking I am doing something wrong because after I use the 'delete' command on my Spot pointer, I can still see the value (and also the spotBehind pointer) afterwards. If it worked the way I wanted to, shouldn't I either see a garbage value and a nulled spotBehind pointer or just not be able to access the data? I would appreciate someone explaining this to me and if I am doing this incorrectly, could someone suggest a way to correctly delete information?

Comment: In C, after you `free` some memory, any use of the old pointer value is Undefined Behaviour (I think also still applies to C++). In short: accessing memory that has been freed **may** work as if it hasn't been freed.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Simple as that. Plus, don't do it.

Comment: Also, try searching [using pointer after delete](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=using+pointer+after+delete)

Comment: @srz2: I have not understood what problem you are trying to solve here which could not be solved by using just a std::list. In C++, the days of implementing one's own linked-list classes are really over... :)

Comment: If you want to know if all your `Spot` are properly deleted, you could add a static counter variable. Increment the variable in `Spot`'s constructor. Decrement it in its destructor. In the end, check that the variable is `0`.

Comment: @pmg Only dereferencing and pointer arithmetic on it are UB. You can still copy or reassign it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your code works as expected.

that the data is still present after the delete is ok, because deletion does not mean that it has to be overwritten.
delete only tells the memory management that the memory the pointer points to will not be used anymore and can be reassigned. accessing it after that operation is illegal and may cause undefined behavior but mostly is possible without any access violations because the address still points to the applications heap.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation is usually implemented with a sort of linked list. Free operation marks the block as available to the system.
Generally what will be done with freed memory depends on the compiler and the type of build - did you print these values in Debug of Release?

For instance, MS compiler in debug mode fills the freed block by

```
memset(pHead, _bDeadLandFill,  // 0xdddddddd
```

Here `0xdddddddd` is special value used by compiler to mark [freed memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260966%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

And attempt to print data of the deleted pointer causes `Access violation` error.
You can try to debug `operator delete` to look how it is implemented in your system.